# How to create a REST webservice with client can get json and client can post data to webservice?

Tags: django, web-services, rest

I have a project to get data from webservice to do jobs 
and post data to webservice to commit.
Client is android application.

Client jobs: get json from webservice and parse like login get username ....
 post: client post data they commit example: change username password

Can i write with django or something like that?
- sorry because my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's an incredibly simple way to set up API's for django models.

Comment: thank you very much but can you give me a sample web service on it?

Comment: If you follow through the instructions it lets you know how to set up the services & test them http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources. Take your Job model, make a JobResource ModelResource for it, edit urls.py and that's it for a basic model api/svc